# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:

Tags: xml, wcf

I faced an issue when trying to call my WCF service method `GetApplicationStatus` from a Java client. The parameter is of `String` type containing xmlcontent

When I invoke the WCF service method, it throws the following exception

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetApplicationStatus'. End element 'xmldoc' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'Patronid' from namespace

The method in class is defined as follows

```
namespace queryService
{
     public class queryService : IqueryService
     {
            public queryService()
            {
            }

            public string GetApplicationStatus(string xmlStringContent)
            {
                 //do some operation
                 return xmlStringContent;
            }
    }
}
```

and the interface is defined as below

```
namespace queryService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IqueryService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetApplicationStatus(string xmlStringContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: xmldoc -  is xml, right? Check it's value in raw request it should be wrapped into CDATA

Comment: xmldoc is a parameter of string type.this string parameter carries xmlcontent as a string

Comment: I see, but i have pretty much same problem with PHP clients, serializer on client side works differently for .net and PHP, that's why i am asking you about catching RAW SOAP XML request

Comment: is there any way around to solve this issue?